# Migrate to Workplace?

Tags: discussion

What do you think of migrating this question to Workplace SE:
https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6639/best-way-to-track-employee-skills

Sounds like the OP is looking for a list of HR tracking tools.

Comment: I asked NickC, a Workplace mod, and he says they'd take it. :)

Comment: It's been migrated. http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4112/best-way-to-track-employee-skills

Answer (score 2):

Agree.  Seems like a better fit for that exchange.